# Golang Compare Two Strings contains same words

Tags: arrays, go

I am trying check if an array contains a particular word with another array like so:

- Example: "3 of hearts" and "5 of hearts" match because they are both
  hearts and should return true.
- Example: "7 of hearts" and "7 of
  clubs" match because they both have the value 7 and should return
  true.
- Example: "Jack of spades" only matches another "Jack of spades"
  and should return true.

How would I go about doing this in golang. I tried a bunch of steps and I'm back in square one what I have so far is this:

```
func compare(firstString, secondString string) bool {
    return false
}

compare("3 of hearts", "5 of hearts")
## This should return true
```

Comment: Does it need to be an array? You can use maps in Go to see if a key in one map exists in the other, which in general should be more efficient than checking if a value in a slice exists in another slice.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid converting the string to an array so I wouldn't have to loop to make the check

Comment: @Zombo I believe this part ``` "jack of spades" only match with "jack of spades"```  indirectly means if I have the same card then they match each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly new to golang but the best way to get this without needing to loop twice would be:

```
func compare(firstString, secondString string) bool {
    f, s := strings.Split(f, " "), strings.Split(secondString, " ")
    if f[0] == s[0] || f[2] == f[2] {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

compare("3 of hearts", "5 of hearts")
## This should return true

compare("7 of hearts", "7 of clubs")
## This should return true

compare("Jack of spades", "Jack of spades")
## This should return true

compare("5 of hearts", "7 of clubs")
## This should return false
```

Answer (score 1):

```golang
func compare(f, s string) bool {
    arr1, arr2 := strings.Split(f, " "), strings.Split(s, " ")
    for _, v1 := range arr1 {
        for _, v2 := range arr2 {
            if v1 == v2 {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

<kbd>[go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/LIskSkSKyUZ)</kbd>

Comment: consider `compare("Jack of spades", "5 of spades")` return `true`. but it should return `false` according to the asker says: "Jack of spades" **only** matches another "Jack of spades"

Comment: This works but I'm trying to avoid the need to loop twice just to compare

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you really want to do. (I mean hello world is boring)
But from the question, at least I know that it might be related to poker.

So you should first design the **structure** related to the playing cards.

Then you need a method to **get the object from the string**

Finally, design an **Equal** function of the card, then done.

---

1. `type Card struct{}`
2. `func GetCardFromStr(str string) (*Card, error)`
3. `func (card *Card) Equal(card2 *Card, criteria criteria) bool`

#### Example Code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type Suit uint8

const (
    Spades Suit = iota + 1
    Hearts
    Diamonds
    Clubs
)

var suitMap map[string]Suit

func init() {
    suitMap = map[string]Suit{"spades": Spades, "hearts": Hearts, "diamonds": Diamonds, "clubs": Clubs}
}

func StrToSuit(str string) Suit {
    if suit, exists := suitMap[strings.ToLower(str)]; exists {
        return suit
    }
    return 0
}

type Card struct {
    point int  // 1-13 // ace, 2 to 10, Jack J, Queen Q, King K
    suit  Suit // spades ♠️, hearts ♥️, diamonds ♦️, clubs ♣️ // emoji suit: https://emojipedia.org/search/?q=Suit
}

func NewCard(point int, suit Suit) (*Card, error) {
    if point < 0 || point > 13 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("illegal point: '%d', it should in the range: 1~13", point)
    }
    return &Card{point, suit}, nil // you can consider checking the suit.
}

func (card *Card) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", map[Suit]string{
        Spades:   "♠️",
        Hearts:   "♥️",
        Diamonds: "♦️",
        Clubs:    "♣️",
    }[card.suit], card.point)
}

type criteria uint8

const (
    Loose criteria = 1 << iota // one of them match
    // ... // others
    Strict // all match
)

func (card *Card) Equal(card2 *Card, criteria criteria) bool {
    if criteria == Strict {
        if card.point == card2.point && (card.suit == card2.suit && card.suit != 0) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    if card.point == card2.point || (card.suit == card2.suit && card.suit != 0) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func GetCardFromStr(str string) (*Card, error) {
    slice := strings.Split(str, " ")
    if slice == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("can't convert string to the card")
    }
    alphaMap := map[string]int{
        "ace":  1,
        "jack": 11, "queen": 12, "king": 13,
    }
    cardPoint := 0
    var cardSuit Suit
    for _, elem := range slice {
        elem = strings.ToLower(elem)
        if cardPoint == 0 {
            checkPoint := true
            if point, exists := alphaMap[elem]; exists {
                cardPoint = point
                checkPoint = false
            }
            if checkPoint {
                if point, err := strconv.Atoi(elem); err == nil {
                    cardPoint = point
                }
            }
        }
        if cardSuit == 0 {
            if suit := StrToSuit(elem); suit != 0 {
                cardSuit = suit
            }
        }
    }

    if cardPoint == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("can't convert string to the card (unknown point)")
    }
    if cardSuit == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("can't convert string to the card (unknown suit)")
    }

    return NewCard(cardPoint, cardSuit)
}

func main() {
    for caseNumber, data := range []struct {
        s1 string
        s2 string
        criteria
    }{
        {"-5 hearts", "5 hearts", Loose},                                            // error illegal point: '-5', it should in the range: 1~13
        {"0", "", Loose},                                                            // error can't convert string to the card (unknown point)
        {"3 of hearts", "3 of hearts", Loose},                                       // true
        {"3 of hearts", "5 of hearts", Loose},                                       // true
        {"7 of hearts", "7 of clubs", Loose},                                        // true
        {"Jack of spades", "Jack of spades", Strict},                                // true
        {"Jack of spades", "Jack spades", Strict},                                   // true
        {"Jack of spades", "Jack hearts", Strict},                                   // false
        {"Jack of spades", "Jack", Strict},                                          // error can't convert string to the card (unknown suit)
        {"Jack of spades", "spades", Strict},                                        // error can't convert string to the card (unknown point)
        {"player Foo: 1 of clubs ", "player bar: I get an Ace of spades !!", Loose}, // true
    } {
        card1, err := GetCardFromStr(data.s1)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("case:%d errMsg:%s\n", caseNumber, err)
            continue
        }
        card2, err := GetCardFromStr(data.s2)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("case:%d errMsg:%s\n", caseNumber, err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("criteria %d, %s equal %s: %v\n",
            data.criteria, card1, card2, card1.Equal(card2, data.criteria),
        )
    }
}
```

<kbd>[go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/XJYEwqNG0_a)</kbd>

By using the above code, I believe no one will be **confused** about the comparison, and you will be able to avoid the downvote.

and then you can turn the question to how to optimize the function `GetCardFromStr` <sup>use *loop one* layer only、 *regexp*、detection of more *edges*...</sup>

---

*Strictly speaking, I am not answering the question but only providing reference to the direction of your question. I hope you don't mind, and good luck.*

Comment: Thank You, Carson! This was in the direction of what I was building.